# Adding KDE and Normal distribution to a Histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

How to add KDE and NOrmal distribution to a dataframe histogram?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.stats import norm

data = pd.DataFrame(norm.rvs(0,1,size=1000))
data.plot.hist()
```

I am familiar with `data.plot.kde()` function how I want scalles to be the same and also add normal distribution plot

And I am also aware of `seaborn` and `distplot` function in it - I need it in `matplotlib`

Comment: `sns.distplot(data, hist=True, kde=True)`?

Comment: Hi thank you very mutch I alredy know about `seaborn` and `distplot` this is just small part in my big function and I need it in `matplotlib`

Comment: Hi thank you very mutch I alredy know about `seaborn` and `distplot` this is just small part in my big function and I need it in `matplotlib`

Comment: In that case, you can plot `kde` in a twin-x axis.

Comment: and add just a gaus normal distribution to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate what I meant in the comment:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data.plot.hist(ax=ax, alpha=0.5)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
data.plot.kde(ax=ax2)
```

Output:

[image]